# Update the First Row in a database C# mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

My problem is that:

1. I want to Select one row from the database, The data should be arrange in expiry (the ones that are not yet expired and I don't want to limit it). The items that passed the current date must be left alone. And with all the same ITEMID lets say I00001.
2. Then after selecting I want to Update the first row of the database. if the quantity reaches 0 then it will go the next row to update and so on.

Here is my example

- Here is the current database [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HASmG.png).
- I want select the itemid where = I00001 and deduct 50.
- Then it should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxADJ.png)
- Then I want to arrange based on the expiry as I mentioned above.
- Select the first row.
- Deduct the 50 from the quantity. (as I also mentioned above).

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM inventory2 WHERE itemid = @itemid ORDER BY expiry ", sqlconnection);

    cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"UPDATE inventory2 SET quantity = @quantity WHERE itemid = @itemid ORDER BY expiry)", sqlconnection);

    sqlconnection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlconnection.Close();
}
```

I'm open for another suggestion in doing this. I hope you understand my problem. Thank you very much. I'm sorry I cannot send another screenshot.

Comment: I would do it all via sql without c# code. But it's 4am and I am off. Will look at it tomorrow

Comment: oh it's ok thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
void UpdateQuantity() {
        // your connection string
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from table where ItemID = " + 13 + " Order BY expiry", cnn); // I have test db and I used it
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        int deductNum = 50;
        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            int value = (int)item["quantity"];
            if (value >= deductNum) // if had enough stock we don't need to pass the next line
            {
                int result = value - deductNum;
                item["quantity"] = result.ToString();
                break; // so need to exit from loop
            }
            else
            {
                deductNum -= value; // else we deduct value count from deduction
                item["quantity"] = 0; // quantity finished so it will be 0
            }
        }
        MySqlCommandBuilder cmb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adp);
        adp.UpdateCommand = cmb.GetUpdateCommand();
        adp.Update(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; //to show the result
    }
```

[image]
(You can calculate :))

Hope helps,

Comment: Thank you. I owe you one

Comment: Hi! I got a chance to try your code but it displays an error. "Additional information: Specified cast is not valid." In int value = Convert.ToInt32((int)item["quantity"]);. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't have Convert in my answer. Cast and Comvert together will give that error. @Philip